# Why is this text showing in my frame?

Tags: beamer, graphics

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {F:\'Surface Tension'} }

\title{My Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{Institute name}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
Some text...

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Surface2}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Why is the circled text showing up? How do I remove it? I am using beamer class. The picture which I want to insert is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ab02A.jpg).

Comment: Without the picture in question there is nothing to be done. Please provide it, to make your MWE compilable

Comment: @DG' I've inserted it.

Comment: Try to put your image in a path without spaces

Comment: Save the image in the same folder as your tex file and comment the line with `\graphicspath`.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer. Also the `\centering` in your figure can be removed, figures are centred by default in beamer

Comment: @samcarter That worked. Can you write the comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Good to hear that it worked! I linked it to a similar questions instead.